# Discord.py: Want to have message.content read as lowercase, .lower() not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

```
import discord
import asyncio
import sys
from discord.ext import commands
client=commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')
id=client.get_guild(-----)
codeword=["codeword"]

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    message.content=message.content.lower()
    if message.content== 'sys.exit()': sys.exit()
    if  message.content in codeword:
        await message.channel.send("{}".format(message.author.display_name))
        await message.delete()
client.run('------')
```

Expected outcome: codeword, regardless of capitalization is removed.

Error: NameError: name 'lower' is not defined

I also tried

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.lower()== 'sys.exit()': sys.exit()
    if  message.content.lower() in codeword:
        await message.channel.send("{}.format(message.author.display_name))
        await message.delete()
```

Error:'str' object has no attribute 'lowercase'

Comment: Your code must work totally fine, did you show the same code in here with your original code? Because in the 2. code blocks, there's no `lowercase` function.

Comment: Btw you shouldn't set message.content to the lowercase content, just make a new variable for that. How Nurqm already said, check the code you've provided us!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend assigning the lower-case version it's own variable like this.

```
messageContent = message.content.lower()
```

So...

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    messageContent = message.content.lower()
    if messageContent == 'sys.exit()': sys.exit()
    if  messageContent in codeword:
        await message.channel.send("{}".format(message.author.display_name))
        await message.delete()
client.run('------')
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should do the trick

```
str(message.content).lower()
```