# how to make nickname channel?

Tags: python, discord

theoretically i know how to change nickname via defined command. this time i just wanted to make a special channel in my server which'd convert all text to user nicknames **without** typing any command/prefix. (and delete this text also). i was trying with a few methods but every was failing. some examples of that:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(ctx):
  if ctx.channel.id != 853665391272263691:
    return
  text = message.content.lower()
  else:
    ctx.author.edit(nick={text})
```

which thrown error:

```
  File "main.py", line 23
    else:
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

second method :

```py
@bot.event
async def bot.on_message(msg):
    if msg.channel.id == 853665391272263691:
        await msg.author.edit(nick=f'{msg.author.name}1')
    else:
        return
```

which was throwing many different errors like
`msg undefined` or just no permissions (when this bot is admin. how?)

after a few tries i tried that. i think i got closer but it yet doesnt work...

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(ctx):
  if ctx.channel.id != 853665391272263691:
    return
  # if ctx.channel.id == 853665391272263691 will continue
  text = str(ctx.content).lower()
  ctx.author.edit(nick=text)
```

which throws error:

```
main.py:24: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Member.edit' was never awaited
  ctx.author.edit(nick=text)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

imported libraries:

```py
import os
from datetime import datetime
import discord
from discord import Embed, Color
from discord.ext import commands
from keep_alive import keep_alive
from discord_slash import SlashCommand
```

no ways to make this charm work or ... ?

full source code **[here](https://replit.com/@hacknorris/bricky-bot#main.py)**

Comment: There's a line between `if` and `else` on the same indentation level which is not allowed.

Comment: need to be because it's variable defining user input

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(ctx):
  if ctx.channel.id != 853665391272263691:
    return
  # if ctx.channel.id == 853665391272263691 will continue
  text = ctx.message.content # before: ctx.message.content.lower()
  await ctx.author.edit(nick=text)
```

> edited

Comment: thank. i got this.. : `  File "main.py", line 23, in on_message
    text = message.content.lower()
NameError: name 'message' is not defined` i dont think that worked...

Comment: I edit it, now it's work

Comment: yet no. read this, then say : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64074333/discord-py-want-to-have-message-content-read-as-lowercase-lower-not-working . i only got `message has no attribute "message" `